# Avoiding duplicated col_keys when creating three way cross tab with flextable tabulator

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, flextable

I am trying to create a threeway crosstab with one variable in the "row position" and two as multilayered columns, using `flextable`'s `tabulator()` function.

Depending on the order of the variables it will either correctly produce the table, or give the error

> error in flextable(dat,col_keys=visible_columns$col_keys) :
> duplicated col_keys.

I would like to know why this is and if there is anything I can change in the underlying data or the tabulator function that I can do avoid the error and use any ordering.

First I create a grouped frequency dataframe, for example:

```
dat <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

and then when I add it in to the tabulator function like so:

```
tabulator(x = dat, rows = "vs", columns = c("cyl", "am"), N = as_paragraph(n)) |>
  as_flextable()
```

I get the above error.

However, when I switch the order of the variables in the tabulator function it seems to work.
For example, reversing "am" and "cyl" like this:

```
tabulator(x = dat, rows = "vs", columns = c("am", "cyl"), N = as_paragraph(n)) |> 
  as_flextable()
```

actually seems to work. Why is this, and is there a way to get the version of the code that throws the error to work?

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. While I get a bunch of warnings both tables are rendered fine on my machine using`flextable` `0.9.2` .

Comment: Ah I am using version 0.7.1 so this must've been fixed later, thanks!